# Run a selenium test in saucelabs Windows7

Tags: selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

I am trying to run a simple test to see if I can run with below capabilities.

```
OS: Windows 7
Browser: Firefox
Browser Version: 33
```

Here is my code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.net.URL;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Tests {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Choose the browser, version, and platform to test
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 7");
        caps.setCapability("version", "33");
        caps.setCapability("browserName", "");
        // Create the connection to Sauce Labs to run the tests
        this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                new URL("http://<axxxxxx>:<5xxxxx@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),
                caps);
    }

    @Test
    public void webDriver() throws Exception {
        // Make the browser get the page and check its title
        driver.get("http://www.amazon.com/");
        assertEquals("Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

When i run this test, it looks like I cannot use Windows 7:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.openqa.selenium.Platform.Windows 7
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.Platform.valueOf(Platform.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities.setCapability(DesiredCapabilities.java:168)
```

I am confused. The website http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp says Windows 7 is supported. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: can you try with `Platform.WINDOWS` in setCapability?

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using? If you use 2.43.0, which is the latest version listed as supported by Sauce Labs, does it work?

Comment: It looks like i need to say platform as VISTA, then it is running on Windows7.DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("version", "33");
        capabilities.setCapability("platform", Platform.VISTA);
        capabilities.setCapability("name", "Windows7Firefox33");

Comment: @VivekSingh, If i tried that option.  If i say Platform.WINDOWS, In which Windows OS it will run.  When i tried this, By default it is using XP.  I want my test to run on Windows 7.

Comment: @Louis, I am using 2.44.0 selenium.  However, I had to make platform as "VISTA".  Now it runs on Windows7

Answer (score 2):

You've run into a **bug in Selenium 2.44.0**. As pointed out in [this article](https://support.saucelabs.com/entries/58597264-java-lang-IllegalArgumentException-No-enum-constant-org-openqa-selenium-Platform-Windows-8-1) in the Sauce Labs knowledge base, you have two options:

1. **The preferred option according to the article is to revert to 2.43.0.**
2. The option you chose: use one of the values in the `Platform` enum rather than a `String`. (It turns out that at least for a while it was no possible to use this option, but the Sauce Labs folks modified their end to allow it.)

The article also points out that the next version of Selenium will have the necessary fix.

Comment: The Selenium issue is at https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8083

Answer (score 1):

Defining capabilities as below solved my problem. Observe VISTA in platform.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); 
capabilities.setCapability("version", "33"); 
capabilities.setCapability("platform", Platform.VISTA); 
capabilities.setCapability("name", "Windows7Firefox33");
```